# Why my Google Sheet document is not updating in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, update, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that updates from a survey I have live in Google forms. I added this to my content in ArcGIS and added as a layer to a map. I was sure to set the refresh interval. I have been checking the map every single time there are changes in the original Google Sheet, but these are not reflected in the map.

I also tried by adding the file directly to the map as a .cvs (Add layer from Web) using the URL provided in google and making sure this is set to 'published'. however, I get the same result. Actually, when I try to do this there is a note saying 'Features will not update if referenced CSV changes.'

So, I would like to know how could this be done. I'm stock with Google sheets as this is linked to the survey, which is where I got my data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a CSV layer as a table from the web return the warning message, "Features will not update if referenced CSV changes" **if no location data is present in the CSV data.**
It is not possible for a Google Sheets Table without a Lat & Long to update in ArcGIS Online.

Surely the below can be tried:-

1. In ArcGIS Online, click Content > Add Item > From cloud drive.
   Click Google Drive.
2. Select the newly added CSV file.
3. Provide all the required details, such as Name and Tag.
4. Click Publish.

Comment: Thanks! I realised that path was very complex, as it never updates live. I decided to remake my survey in Survey 123. Job done, so much better